# counter=$ unexpected in the shell script

Tags: bash, shell, solaris, sh

I have below lines in my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
counter=$((counter+1))
echo $counter
```

And I need to run the above shell script like this-

```
sh -x test.sh
```

Whenever I try to run the above script, I awlays get error as -

```
`counter=$' unexpected
```

Any suggestions what changed I need to make there?

**Updated Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
counter=$(($counter+1))
echo $counter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/sh

counter=0
counter=`expr $counter + 1`
echo $counter
```

`$  sh -x test.sh`

```
+ counter=0
++ expr + 1
+ counter=1
+ echo 1
1
```

Comment: Thanks sudo for the suggestions. Can you tell me how you ran the above script? You executed the script like this `sh -x test.sh` ? As I have already tried that and it gives me the same error. :(

Comment: Either `bash -x test.sh` or `sh -x test.sh` should work, what platform are you on? Post `bash --version`..

Comment: With the `bash` it's working but not with `sh`. How can I make that work with `sh`. Any idea?

Comment: bash-3.00$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `bash` instead of `sh` since `$(( ... ))` isn't standard.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an older version of `sh`. Try using following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
counter=`expr $counter + 1`
echo $counter
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest reverting to an outdated syntax.

Using `sh -x test.sh` is defeating your scripts's shebang `#!/bin/bash`. You force sh to be used as the interpreter to parse your script instead of /bin/bash. Up to Solaris 10 included, /bin/sh is the original bourne shell with pre POSIX syntax. It shouldn't be used but in legacy scripts.

You can then simply state a shell that understands your syntax, i.e. one of:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/sh -x test.sh
```

or

```
/bin/bash -x test.sh
```

or

```
/bin/ksh -x test.sh
```

Should you really want `sh -x test.sh` to work as is, just switch to the POSIX mode by setting your path like this:

```
PATH=/usr/xpg6/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:$PATH
```